# comparing constructs in clang AST parser

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

While parsing an ASTVisitor in Clang in sample codes, I see there constructs to verify statements eg.

```
isa<IfStmt>(statement) 
isa<UnaryOperator>(Expression)
```

Is there a comprehensive list of such constructs which are used to evaluate a current expression/statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's nothing magical about `isa`, that's just LLVM's way of checking whether an object is a subtype of some class; the expression `isa<IfStmt>(statement)` is basically equivalent to this RTTI-enabled expression:

```
dynamic_cast<IfStmt*>(statement) != NULL
```

So your question really boils down to what the AST hierarchy is; and for that, it's best to check these four pages, with complete hierarchy chart:

- [`Type`'s hierarchy](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html)
- [`Decl`'s hierarchy](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html)
- [`DeclContext`'s hierarchy](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclContext.html)
- [`Stmt`'s hierarchy](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Stmt.html) (this includes `Expr` and its children)